# Surah 16:25 and surah 34:25-26

Tags: quran, hadith, tafseer

How is a working explanation made? (emphasis mine)

> 16:25 That they may bear their own burdens [i.e., sins] in full on the Day of Resurrection and some OF THE BURDENS OF THOSE whom they misguide without [i.e., by lack of] knowledge. Unquestionably, evil is that which they bear.
> — Saheeh International

> 34:25 Say, "YOU WILL NOT BE ASKED about what we committed, and we will not be asked about what you do."
> — Saheeh International
> 34:26 Say, "Our Lord will bring us together; then He will judge between us in truth. And He is the Knowing Judge."
> — Saheeh International

One will not be asked for what they used to do, yet one will be responsible for errors done by one who he has misled? I don't understand.

Comment: Please use the formatting tools when writing a question/answer. And try to only use the English translation, without the Arabic unless it is related to Arabic Grammer/Vocabulary. Also quote citation/reference using >.

Comment: One will bear the burden of whom they misguide (without reducing their burden in the slightest), and the disbelievers will not be asked what the Muslims do and vice versa because neither group caused the other to do what they did (they didn't misguide them).

Comment: @AbduRahman done

Answer (score 2):

I don't get the confusion. I will try to explain how I have understood it.

1. Everyone is responsible for their deeds (good and bad)
2. If a person is involved in misleading another person, he gets extra punishment.
3. If a person becomes a source for someone else's guidance, they get extra    rewards.
4. In case we invite someone else to Islam (for example - Christians) and they don't accept it; we can move on. It is not our duty to debate with them until everyone comes to same conclusion. We can just move ahead. They will get return for their deeds and we will get return for our deeds.

- Verse 16:25 is concerned with points 1 and 2.
- Verse 34:25 - 26 is concerned with point 4.

**Note**: In case you choose to down-vote my answer, you are most welcome. But leave a comment explaining your down-vote. I will not argue with you. I am posting this I have faced down-votes earlier in this forum without any explanation.

Comment: Although fourth point is explained well, 34:25 has a different context.

Comment: @AbduRahman You are correct. Here it is intended as a warning to mushrikoon.